# Type mismatch: inferred type is T! but T & Any was expected

Tags: android, kotlin

I have following code:

```
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T & Any {

        return try {
            modelClass.getConstructor(DataRepository::class.java).newInstance(mRepository)
        } catch (e: InstantiationException) {...}
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

This case occurs mostly when a @NotNull annotated Java method call is used in Kotlin code. You can solve this error by changing the given parameter type from **T** to **T & Any**.

Related JetBrains ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-20425

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the code to this and now it works:

```
override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return try {
            modelClass.getConstructor(DataRepository::class.java).newInstance(mRepository)
        } catch (e: InstantiationException) {}
}
```